# Run SQL script via command line to remote server

Tags: sql-server

I have a large SQL script which I am trying to run using the command line.

I have found these instructions here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/scripting/sqlcmd-run-transact-sql-script-files

Which seem to say that I can use this command:

```
sqlcmd -S myServer\instanceName -i C:\myScript.sql
```

Which makes sense to me. I assume I would use the same server details as I would in a Web.Config connection string.

The issue is, this does not seem to specify the database name to run the script on.

I think this is because it is assumed that the SQL file will have the DB name, but my file is too big to open to confirm this.

Also, I would like to specify the DB name to be double safe.

Can anyone advise how to do this?

Also, if anyone can advise how I can read the first line of a file using the command line that would be great aswell..

Thanks in advance

Comment: -d Specifies the database name - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlcmd-utility

Comment: You find out all the parameters for sqlcmd by running `sqlcmd -?`. That tells you use can use `-d` to specify the database name. Thus: `sqlcmd -S myServer\instanceName -i C:\myScript.sql -d MyDatabase`. This command also assumes you are using integrated security.

Comment: @Ctznkane525 that is the correct answer, if you write that as answer I will accept it

Comment: I'm curious how large this file is that you can't open it in a text editor.  Notepad++ handles large text files more gracefully than Notepad if you can't get the standard notepad to open it.  I've never tried to open a .sql file in server management studio that was anywhere near that size though.

Comment: @EMUEVIL SSMS does start to struggle quite early on, from my experience. I wouldn't trust it opening a file 100MB or more. I certainly can't open the >=500MB files I have in SSMS. notepad++ will open them, but you can't execute them from there.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

-d -  Specifies the database name - learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlcmd-utility – Ctznkane525

```
sqlcmd -S myServer\instanceName -i C:\myScript.sql -d DatabaseName
```

Answer (score 6):

in my case I needed SQL Server Authentication

```
sqlcmd -d database_name -U sa -P Password  -S 192.168.1.1 -i "D:\tmp\script.sql"
```

so I launched sqlcmd with these switches. I Hope that this can help somebody